# Better way of distributing objects/classes inside a project

Tags: java

I have some Classes like `Clipboard` or `ProcessRegister` that I only want to run once in my Project, so only one instance.

My Question in now: **How do I distribute those instances best in my Project.**

ATM both are singleton and object they use the get an instance over the `getInstance()`.

Another Idea of mine is to create a class `Project`, that has some static methods like `getProjectClipboard()`or `getProcessRegister()`that return the instances.

What is the best way to distribute them? Are there any patterns for that?

Greetings Dennis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are mainly two patterns that can be used: the service locator, and dependency injection. The service locator pattern is probably the one you are referring to, where everywhere you look for a reference for these objects you explicitly retrieve it from a central location, which for simple java applications is usually a bunch of static methods. this is OK, and I don't think there is an overall better approach here, just make sure that you have only one static method for each singleton, and that you call it always.

Then a few years ago, a shift of mentality became mainstream, dependency injection, and its more popular framework... Spring, with this paradigm, in each place you need to access this singletons, you don't specify where they are, but your object get the correct references injected...

I would recommend you to look into dependency injection... and probably Spring, as it is the mainstream solution for it... I think that giving you more insgight into Spring is out of the scope of the question, but there is A LOT of documentation in Internet if you search for Spring tutorials or something similar...

Basically what you would do is create as spring beans each of your singletons, and then have spring injecting them into your objects... The caveat to this approach is that all of your objects have to be built by Spring, but in practice it doesn't suppose any disadvantage, it will actually make your life easier in terms of testings, maintenance...

Comment: Dependency injection is what you need (if you want to learn some good patterns). DI wired code is much easier to test than code with service locator or singletons witc static methods. Take a look at Google Guice too. It's "smaller" than Spring.

Answer (score 2):

Singletons, when done at language level, are global objects. This may work for small projects but is not the best idea when the project grows. There may evolve a situation where suddenly a singleton is only a singleton relative to a certain scope. Then you have to touch the object and every access to it.

That said if you have a `Project` object or an `Application` object these are good places to have accessors to `Project`-relative singletons. If `Project` is just a class that provides a lot of `static` accessors it is like a namespace. It is a win in clarity and will make refactoring easier but it doesn't change much in terms of architecture.

Best way to do singletons is not on language level but on application level. Very helpful are application and dependency frameworks like Spring (where the standard scope for beans is in fact singleton). If you later on see that the object isn't singleton you just change the configuration - but not the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who is usually against the usage of stateful singletons (except for caching purposes), I would say: have one instance of these classes per running application and inject them where you need them (see Dependency Injection). That will also allow you to run the same application multiple times with different configuration in the same JVM.